# Is there some crashreporting library for java applications?

Tags: java, monitoring, microservices, reliability

I wan't to be able to perform Asserts in production runtime, and send out crash reports (with CRITICAL or WARNING messages) through different channels. Emails being one of them.

As you can see, I wan't this library to be performing collection of most commonly required stats - like Stacktrace, Host details, configurations etc.

Comment: Some of the Java logging libraries can use e-mail as an appender.

Comment: However, I also want some constructs to collect required contextual data. This could both system related and application related. For application related contextual information - I am looking at a library that exposes some hooks which I can fill in.

Comment: If you can come up with detailed requirements, you *might* get help on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Spring Cloud Sleuth or something like a Redis appender to send to an ELK stack then use the ELK stack for your needs.

[Redi Appender - Github Repo](https://github.com/ryantenney/log4j-redis-appender)

[Spring Cloud Sleuth Project](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/)